# How do I make Noise texture stretch from the top of a cone?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

So I have a Cone here and I stretched the nosie texture so it looks like lines and I want them to be coming out from the top of the cone instead of going one direction this is what it looks like:
[image]

But I want it to look like this with the lines coming out from the peak

[image]

Also I want help with making all the lines have the same thickness.

Also here is the node set up: [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Gradient Texture (Radial* mode), and use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate*:

[image]

Comment: thanks this helped also how would I bake it? I used diffuse with direct and indirect lighting unchecked and just the color and the lines come out low quality and squiggly I added the image to the post above

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7EXmsQ5o" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7EXmsQ5o/)                                                                                                         

and the full bake result texture image is on the above post

Comment: You need to put the 2 objects at the same location, add at least an horizontal edge loop at the top, choose the front view and unwrap with the Cylinder Projection mode, create an image that is large enough (at least 2048 x 2048), bake

Comment: I followed all the steps but I get the same result

Comment: check the file (also I've given a bit of Extrusion but not sure it was useful): https://blend-exchange.com/b/b70Ds8zk

Comment: thank you i found the solution